# Why are connectEnd and connectStart equal for documents loaded in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, navigation-timing-api

I'm using the Navigation Timing API to gather some basic network performance measurements like so:

1. From a page in **Domain A**, insert an iframe into the DOM which downloads another page in **Domain B**, applying a lengthy random query string to the **Domain B** URL for cache-busting purposes.
2. JavaScript in the Domain B page waits a couple seconds and then reads the contents of window.performance.timing.

The numbers look as expected except for one thing: connectEnd almost always equals connectStart.  Unless I misunderstand what's going on, there should be no persistent connection in play, and the browser shouldn't be retrieving the **Domain B** document from cache.  Therefore, the browser should be establishing a new connection to **Domain B**, and connectEnd minus connectStart should reflect the time it takes to do that.

I've tested this in Firefox, Chrome and IE (IE 10).  In Firefox and IE, I've only observed connectEnd equal to connectStart.  They're generally equal in Chrome as well, but I did see connectEnd greater to connectStart once.

A test page is available at http://test-pages.s3.amazonaws.com/test-navtiming.html which downloads another test page at http://www.wildlemur.com/files/navtiming.html (plus a random query string).  The values of connectStart and connectEnd are displayed in the browser console.

What is the reason that connectEnd is so often equal to connectStart in this scenario?